# is an ambiguous behaviour for sigsegv

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, signals, ipc

NOTE: SEGSEGV is blocked when I raised a SIGSEGV like, `raise(SIGSEGV);` but not on dereferencing of `NULL` pointer or memory violation. what is the issue here?

Code:

```
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
       psignal(signo,"i am in sig_handler\n");
}

int main()
{
    sigset_t intmask;
    int c = 0, *p = NULL;

    if((signal(SIGSEGV , sig_handler)) == SIG_ERR)
             perror("signal call is failed\n");
    if ((sigemptyset(&intmask) == -1) || (sigaddset(&intmask, SIGSEGV) == -1))    
          perror("Failed to initialize the signal mask");
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &intmask, NULL);
    fprintf(stdout, "SIGINT signal blocked\n");
    c = *p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual page for [`sigprocmask()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigprocmask) has the answer:

> If SIGBUS, SIGFPE, SIGILL, or SIGSEGV are generated while they are blocked, the result is undefined, unless the signal was generated by `kill(2)`, `sigqueue(3)`, or `raise(3)`.